# Fetch related record from Array by give element in TextBox

Tags: arrays, aurelia, custom-element

I am working in Aurelia .I have very simple scenario is that on HTML page only button and one textbox is showing and when user write text in textbox and click on button then all related record from array should be display of given text.For Example if user write "Aamir" then related records to amir ("Aamir Hussain and Rollnumber : 413 ) should be displayed on screen in table format or simple string .

```
entries = [
    {rollNumber: 413, name: 'Aamir Hussain'},
    {rollNumber: 405, name: 'Adil Hussain'},
  ];
```

I tried many methods but unable to find a solution of my problem

Answer (score 3):

Here's a GistRun (Google Chrome is best): https://gist.run/?id=7d49e5adafe359a165ddd8423830ef92

**app.html**

```
<template>
    <input type="text" value.bind="searchText"></input>
    <p>${foundItem}</p>
</template>
```

**app.js**

```
import {observable} from 'aurelia-framework';

export class App {
  @observable() searchText;

  entries = [
    {rollNumber: 413, name: 'Aamir Hussain'},
    {rollNumber: 405, name: 'Adil Hussain'},
  ];

  searchTextChanged() {
    let foundEntry = this.entries.find(entry => entry.name.startsWith(this.searchText));

    if (foundEntry) {
      this.foundItem = `${foundEntry.name} and Rollnumber : ${foundEntry.rollNumber}`;
    } else {
      this.foundItem = '';
    }
  }
}
```

I highly recommend you watch [Beginning Aurelia Development](https://vimeo.com/ondemand/beginningaurelia).

Comment: Was this helpful or are you trying to do something other than this?